# Relação um para muitos entre entidades

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho o seguinte esquema de base de dados:

[image: Esquema da base de dados]

Neste esquema pretende-se o seguinte:

1 user pode ter várias teams e uma team pode ter até dois utilizadores (assumi que é uma relação de muitos para muitos e depois valido se uma equipa tem ou não só dois utilizadores)

1 team pode ter vários jogos e um jogo apenas tem um home_team (team) e uma away_team (team) aqui assumi que terá então duas relações 1 para muitos (1 team tem vários jogos e um jogo apenas tem uma away_team e uma home_team).

A minha dúvida é como devo fazer as relações deles nos modelos, para, por exemplo, conseguir através de um utilizador obter todos os jogos dele, tanto away_team como home_team.

Answer (score -3):

Você pode definir seus modelos assim:

```
<?php

// Model User
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    //  .... 

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'teams_users', 'user_uuid', 'team_uuid');
    }
}


// Model team
// php artisan make:model Team
class Team extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'teams_users', 'team_uuid', 'user_uuid');
    }

    public function homeTeamGames()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Game::class, 'games', 'home_team_uuid');
    }

    public function awayTeamGames()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Game::class, 'games', 'away_team_uuid');
    }
}

// Model game
// php artisan make:model Game
class Game extends Model
{
    public function homeTeam()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'teams', 'uuid');
    }

    public function awayTeam()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'teams', 'uuid');
    }
}
```

Exemplo query capturando usuarios + times

`$users = User::with(['teams'])->get();`